# How to replace "N.A. " with regex for a panda column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in my dataframe called "Rank" and I need to replace all the values "N.A. " with 0.
Every time I use replace I get an error.

Dataframe looks like:

```
index Rank
0     100000
1     N.A. 
2     120000
3     N.A.
```

Here is the code I have tried:

```
import pandas as pd

df['Rank'] = df['Rank'].replace({'\\N.A. ': '0'}, regex=True)
```

Error: re.error: missing { at position 2

```
import pandas as pd

df['Rank'].str.replace('N.A. ','0')
```

This gives me the error: ValueError: Unable to parse string "N.A. " at position 1514

Output expected:

```
index Rank
0     100000
1     0
2     120000
3     0
```

I am not sure what to do next, any help is appreciated!

Comment: It's just another rank, 394,073.

Comment: Is there a tailing whitespace after 'N.A.  '  or is it just 'N.A.'?

Comment: There is a whitespace but I add the whitespace in the code too.

Comment: You could also try to specify zero or more white spaces after 'N.A.' like `df['Rank'].str.replace('N.A.\s?', '0', regex=True)`. Add a `.astype(int)` if you want an integer column as result.

Answer (score 0):

If you are replacing just `'N.A. '` value for column `Rank`, you can directly write the following:

```
df['Rank'] = df['Rank'].replace('N.A.','0')
```

Comment: Hmm, there must be wrong with the file. I keep getting this error: ValueError: Unable to parse string "N.A. " at position 1514. Even if I delete 1514, it just goes to 1513 and so on.

Comment: @Thomas166 is it really 'N.A. ' what appears in the the original file or an empty value?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is using a plain replace:

```py
df['Rank'] = df['Rank'].replace({'N.A. ': 0})
```

But if you have some reason to use regex (e.g., strip blank spaces around 'N.A.'), here you are:

```py
df['Rank'] = df['Rank'].replace(regex={r' *N\.A\. *': 0})
```

Comment: Thank you! It must be because there are white spaces before or after the N.A., this works!

Answer (score 0):

Single line -

```
import numpy as np
df['Rank'].replace('N.A. ', np.NaN).fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Rank'].str.replace('N.A.', '0')
```

works for me, with your sample dataframe.

In your command

```
df['Rank '].str.replace('N.A. ','0')
```

you have

- a space after `Rank` in `df['Rank ']`,
- a space after `N.A.` in `replace('N.A. ','0')`.

Mayby this is the problem.